# Alignment of reports in SSRS Server in non-aphabetical order

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

SSRS 2014:
Once the SSRS reports are deployed into SSRS Server, these reports gets aligned in the alphabetical order A-Z. Is there a way we can that we can change this reports alignment in SSRS Server(in deployed server).

Below 3 Reports are deployed to SSRS Server and gets arranged in this order(A-Z):
Report-Month, Report-Week, Report-Year

I want to align the reports in this order:
Report-Week, Report-Month, Report-Year

I could not find any option, please let me know if we can do it!!
Thanks

Comment: The Report Server Portal should not be part of the user interface of your custom application. In a "custom application", you can provide links to the reports in any desired order.

Comment: As a simple workaround, you could experiment with adding special characters to the report title -- perhaps a second dash, a period, or a space could change the sort order, though I haven't personally tested this.